# How to fix "System doesn't have any USB boot system"?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, bios, tablet

I try all my best to get the boot bios to perform my upgrade in my laptop but It end to pain in my neck coz I cant get the right one process. It always said like this every time I try."System doesn't have any USB boot system? Please select other option in boot manager."

Answer (score 4):

Which version of BIOS so you have?

According to [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/110162/Add+Boot+Option+using+Insydeh20+setup+utility), insydeH20 **A9** should allow you to do this. The issue is UEFI. You need to enable legacy boot.

1. Start the machine and hit F2 to get to BIOS.
2. Disable secure boot in the boot options screen.
3. Enable the load legacy option ROM.
4. Keep the boot list option set to UEFI.
5. Press F10 to save and exit.
6. Shut down the machine and start it again with the USB device attached.
7. Press F12 on boot to get the legacy boot options.
8. Pick USB from the list, and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

Experience shows that this may be either caused by the USB device not being bootable or your BIOS having an incorrect boot setting.

Do you have an option to change between **legacy** and **UEFI** boot?

**NOTE** that changing boot options may cause corrupt data on your current disk so make sure you back it up first if required.

Try each one of those and see whether you can boot from USB.
Remember that you may need to change the boot order to USB devices first or if it's possible to choose a boot option during start-up, choose the USB device.

Comment: That is the problem sir coz I don't know how to change my option theirs no legacy nor UEFI that indicate in my boot manager. The brand of what I'm using is I-Life Zednote and in my Setup Utility was InsydeH20. I try searching about boot BIOS related to my brand but I got no and it all appeared was a well known brand like Acer, Dell, Samsung, Toshiba and etch. I think InsydeH20 setup utility was a rare type? Well thank you and if you have any idea about this please help me coz I really need it ASAP I'm doing my project.

Answer (score -1):

look at the list of [about three] options presented after this "problem screen" (directly after pressing enter/equivalent while presented with the "system doesn't have any..."); the "technical name" of your device (it may say brand-name [mine said Sandisk], etc) might be listed in an unassuming manner, as was done on my screen. I worked through it several times before I realized it had been working the entire time - and that's why I couldn't fix it! :)